Problem while uploading sketch
Hello I just tried to upload a simple sketch to my arduino Uno and the sketch is uploading forever and when I try to change the USB port where my arduino is connected no matter the port I putt the arduino in the IDE always says it is COM3.
Here is the error code I get while uploading:
avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Apr 15 2015 at 19:59:58
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.0.1-arduino5/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM3
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x74
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x74
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x74
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x74
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x74
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x74
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x74
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x74
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x74
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x74

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1

Could you help me out to be able to upload my code to my arduino

what com port name does the windows device manager report?

What's the model of the USB-to-Serial chip on your Arduino board? If it's something like CH340G, you need to install additional driver before uploading your sketches.

Good day!
The error you are getting is a very generic one. It simply says that the Arduino IDE can't establish a connection with your Board.
There are many reasons such as:
-Bad USB cable
-Wrong board setting in the IDE
-Missing Bootloader
-Bricked Arduino
-Loose USB port
etc.
But from what I read here, it's most likely that COM3 is not really your Arduino but some other Serial port on the Computer. (Certain internal devices use these)
To check if that is the case, try disconnecting your Arduino and checking wether it still offers COM3 as a port.
If the port is gone it's either:
-Wrong board setting (Tools > Board)
-Broken board or cable
If the port is still available after you've removed your Arduino it means that said port is something else.
In that case my main suspect would be a missing CH340 driver. Try installing that, rebooting your computer and see if there is another COM port available.
The last suspect would be a Power-only USB cable. While these tend to be rare, I've come across them before. Try switching the cable for a different one.
If all that doesn't help, your Arduino might be broken.
